# Python: numpy.matrix.resize moves elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix:

```
[[ 0.   0.2  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.2]
 [ 0.   0.   0. ]]
```

when I resize it `matrix.resize(4, 4)`, to have one extra row and column, it becomes:

```
[[ 0.   0.2  0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.2  0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0. ]]
```

The element on the second row is moved one to the left. It seems all elements are moved, and `0.`'s are added at the bottom.

I would expect the matrix to become:

```
[[ 0.   0.2  0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.2  0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0. ]
 [ 0.   0.   0.   0. ]]
```

How can I fix this?

Note that I'm doing this for many different matrices, with many different values in it. So I'm looking for a simple solution that works for any size matrix, though the added column and row should contain all 0's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`np.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to pad the array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ 0.,   0.2,  0. ],
                [ 0.,   0.,   0.2],
                [ 0.,   0.,   0. ]])
np.pad(arr, pad_width=([0,1], [0,1]), mode='constant')
```

yields

```
array([[ 0. ,  0.2,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.2,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

`pad_width=([0,1], [0,1])` tells `np.pad` to add

- zero rows on top
- one row on the bottom
- zero columns on the left
- one column on the right

`mode='constant'` uses 0 as the default constant pad value. There are lots of
other modes, such as 'reflect', 'linear_ramp', 'edge', 'constant', 'minimum',
'wrap', 'symmetric', 'median', 'maximum', 'mean'.

Answer (score 1):

np.pad does the job:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print a

b=np.pad(a, ((0,2),(0,1)), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
print b
```